# IAPs work in Live App Testing, but not in the Appstore version

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, kindle-fire

We trying to integrate the latest version of [the amazon In-App Purchasing (IAP) API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-overview.html). Everything seems to work just fine when the app is sideloaded onto my test devices (Kindle Fire) and used with the Amazon App Tester and Json file. The IAPs can be purchased without any problem, but doesn't work when it goes live.

[image: Application status is live]

[image: In-app purchaises status is live]

This is the log output when using the loaded on version with App Tester:

`10-04 12:05:24.420 920-1338/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.canary is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.420 920-1831/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.fv is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.450 920-1837/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.canary is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.450 920-1263/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.fv is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.470 920-1264/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.canary is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.470 920-999/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.fv is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.540 920-1230/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.canary is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.540 920-1398/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.fv is not installed for user 0
10-04 12:05:24.570 920-1338/? W/PackageManager: com.amazon.canary is not installed for user 0`

Actually the Amazon forum seems not to be a good place to get help. I also contacted Amazon directly, so far without any feedback as well.

Is this a known issue? How can this be solved?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just wanted to clarify Live App Testing is not the same as Amazon App Tester. At a high level:

- [Amazon App Tester](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-testing-overview.html) lets you test IAP locally in sandbox mode.
- [Live App Testing (LAT)](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-testing/live-app-testing-getting-started.html) lets you test in the live environment. You would download the published apk from Appstore to test.

If IAP works with App Tester but not in LAT or Prod, then follow [this guide](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-obfuscate-the-code.html) to ensure the com.amazon.* namespace is not code obfuscated.

If IAP works in LAT but not in Prod, then you should contact [Amazon Developer Support](https://developer.amazon.com/support).

Comment: @AlexeyShtanko , I am facing some issue while running IAP app in Live App testing. App shows "An error occurred while processing your purchase". Please help me in it, I am stuck here since last 4 days.